# Processing GRIB data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, weather, grib

Does anyone know of a .NET library for processing [GRIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB) data?

Comment: It seems that [GRIB.US](http://www.grib.us/) is written in .NET.  Perhaps they used an open source library?

Comment: do you have any feedback on how you did finally proceed?

Comment: @apneadiving, I haven't had to cross this hurdle just yet.  This question was really just a feeler...

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I keep on searching ;)

Comment: @apneadiving, check out HaLaBi's answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for keeping me updated :)

Comment: You're welcome.  BTW I guess from your name that you're into free diving.  Check out a diving site I built, though it's more geared towards scuba diving: http://diveseven.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[check this out](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gribcs/)
I think this is what you are looking for..

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be the only freely available .NET library for this.

Answer (score 5):

[GribApi.NET](https://github.com/0x1mason/GribApi.NET) is now freely available under the Apache 2 license. It supports reading and writing GRIB 1 and 2 files.

Disclosure: I am the author of the C# wrapper.